# How to put Image on Buttonfield and add events

Tags: java, blackberry

I want to develop a java application.

How can I create an imagebutton?  How do I put an Image on a ButtonField, 
and add click and navigate events to it?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912223/image-button-in-blackberry

Answer (score 2):

There's plenty of material out there on how this could be accomplished. You can override extend ButtonField and override its paint method to do what you want.  You can use a BitmapField and provide the entire image for your button. Here are some links that should help:

http://www.coderholic.com/blackberry-custom-button-field/

[BlackBerry - ButtonField with centered Bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1706241/blackberry-buttonfield-with-centered-bitmap)

Then for implementing navigation functionality, you need to override the navigation methods provided by Field.  Such methods include Field#navigationClick(int, int) and Field#keyDown(int, int). Here's a link to the JavaDocs for Field.java.

http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Field.html

Comment: Thank you very much.It's very helpful links.